# Prevent user interaction with SKScene under UIViewController

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a SKScene that acts as somewhat of a main menu. And I use container views that have various view controllers such as settings etc...

The problem is, players can still tap on nodes etc behind the view controller in the container view. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: It depends....how did you setup your 1) containerview, 2) scene, 3) taps?

Comment: The container view is setup via the storyboard and the scene is added via the view controller code. The taps are tap gesture recognisers applied via the scene.

Comment: A picture of your storyboard and the code for tap gestures would go a long way to helping us solve your problem. We can only put as much work in as you provide information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had help from a friend who wrote an extension that solved this, presented the view over the top:

```
extension UIViewController {
var topPresentedViewController: UIViewController {
    if let vc = self.presentedViewController {
        return vc.topPresentedViewController
    }

    return self
}
```

}